# Shrink frames in beamer export from orgmode

Tags: org-mode, latex, beamer

How can I send a shrink option to a beamer frame?

I already tried with

```
*** frame title
:PROPERTIES:
:BEAMER_envargs: [shrink=5]
:END:
```

as suggested in https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2011-01/msg00078.html, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `BEAMER_opt`, not `BEAMER_envargs`.